# paypal adaptive payment rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, activemerchant

How to use ipn notification with paypal apadaptive payment gem with active merchant?
I want to avoid using metal, directly a controller wanna use. 
rails 3
ruby 1.9.2
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using like this

```
response = gateway.setup_purchase(
    :return_url => url_for(:action => 'index',:port=>"3001", :only_path => false),
    :cancel_url => url_for(:action => 'create',:port=>"3001", :only_path => false),
    **:ipn_notification_url => payments_notify_action_url**,
    :receiver_list => recipients
)
```

Here you specify the IPN notification URL and then:

```
def notify_action
    notify = ActiveMerchant::Billing::Integrations::PaypalAdaptivePayment::Notification.new(request.raw_post)
    p "Notification object is #{notify}"
    if notify.acknowledge
    p "Transaction ID is #{notify.transaction_id}"
    p "Notification object is #{notify}"
    p "Notification status is #{notify.status}"
end
```

Before that go to the sandbox account.

1. Choose the test account.
2. Then click any business account -> click "Enter sandbox account"
3. Enter email of business account and type password
4. Choose -> profile settings -> ipn notification -> set return url

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this gem that encapsulates it all for your convenience:
https://github.com/jpablobr/active_paypal_adaptive_payment